# This JavaScript Function Works Alone, But Not With Other JavaScript Functions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#target-share ul li').click(function() {
            $('input#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

and it really works as I expected. but when I add this another javascript to do drop-down animation, that javascript not working anymore :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select-shareto a").click(function () {
        var newClass = $(this).find("span").attr('class');
        var newText = $(this).find("span").text();
        $("#select-shareto a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("a#to-chosen span").removeClass().addClass(newClass).text(newText);
        $("a#to-chosen").toggleClass("opened");
        $('#select-shareto').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });

    $('a#to-chosen').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("opened");
        $('#select-shareto').slideToggle('fast', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

those javascript actually affected on this HTML code :

```
<div id="target-share">
<a href="#" title="" id="to-chosen" class="default"><span class="to-admin">Admin</span></a>
<ul id="select-shareto">
<li data-val="0-1">
<a href="#" title="" class="selected"><span class="to-Finance">Finance</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="1-1">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-admin-private">Admin Private</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="1-0">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-ceo">CEO</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="0-0">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-ceo-private">CEO Private</span></a>
</li>                                    
</ul>
<input id="shareto" type="text" value="0-1" name="shareto">
</div><!-- #target-share -->
```

any idea how to make those 2 javascript works side-by-side? thanks.

Comment: They work alone and they prefer to be by themselves.

Comment: Is there anything in the Javascript console? Maybe you misplaced a brace somewhere

Comment: Why you are passing the "$" as paramter in the first function to the "ready" event?

Comment: Ok, seriously now.  Have you tried putting it into a single ready function block?

Comment: @kakridge: That doesn't matter. @Estefano: That's a common technique to ensure that `$` really points to `jQuery`, especially when used with `noConflicts()`

Comment: @Bergi - Been a while. Do multiple ready() calls get appended in some sort of collection?

Comment: Yes, you always can attach multiple event handlers to the same event. For this special (non-DOM) one, jQuery holds the callback array itself. Also [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#select-shareto a").click(function () {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Hereby, you stop the further propagation of this event - other handlers for this `click` event won't be called any more. Instead, use this:

```
$("#select-shareto a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/G8UXy/))

Comment: IT WORKS!!! thanks bro!!! I must wait another 3 minutes to toggle your answer... great job, bro!! thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you tried to insert the code where the comment animation complete is and if so you just need to put the code:`$('#target-share ul li').click(function() { $('input#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));});`

Your code is already wrapped in a `$(document).ready` so you don't need another one.